# Are ninja tuck jumps safe?

Tags: exercise, injury-prevention

I recently stumbled upon a exercise called "ninja tuck jumps" as shown in this article:
[25 Most Deceiving Exercises - Ninja Tuck Jumps](http://www.shape.com/fitness/25-most-deceiving-exercises-they-tone-more-you-think?page=12)

See also these videos:

- [Ninja jump with a tuck jump](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fug09TvDC5Y)
- [Zuzana Light - ZWOW # 21](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRYqkRzmLEY)

Is this exercise safe? How high is the risk of injury doing this exercise, how high is the risk to damage something in long term doing this?

I should add that I am in very good shape and it's not a problem for me to do this, however I just have the feeling that it might be not safe. Are there any form pointers for this type of exercise to make it safer?

Comment: The link should be OK now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knee problems are a contraindication for this exercise. Lower back issues could be aggravated, I suppose, especially if there are already structural imbalances. Some people can't even really do the kneeling part due to ankle inflexibility, at least if it starts from a full kneel (not shown in the video).

IMO a healthy person should have no issues doing this exercise from an injury standpoint.

On a personal note, I think it's a great exercise myself, although I like to vary things by landing in, or moving to, an athletic position rather than a simple squat. Following with a tuck-jump amps it up several notches. Followed by breakfalls and/or rolls is very entertaining, and amuses others at the gym.